# How to call function in another page?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, rest, web-services

I created a link https://www.sefaz.rs.gov.br/NFE/NFE-CCC.aspx?ErrKey=true&iCodUf=0&lCnpj=00110612000137 To fill the input field CNPJ.

This is fine. However, I need to run the function **preencheParametros('CNPJ')** together above link.

So, I tried something like this https://www.sefaz.rs.gov.br/NFE/NFE-CCC.aspx?ErrKey=true&iCodUf=0&lCnpj=00110612000137&exec=preencheParametros('CNPJ')

And not worked. **How handle this?**

First Way: Not Worked
**GET method**

```
<form method="post" action="https://www.sefaz.rs.gov.br/NFE/NFE-CCC.aspx?ErrKey=true&iCodUf=0" name="nForm" id="nForm">
    <div class="CInput" id="CCnpj">
        <input type="text" name="lCnpj" id="lCnpj" value="00110612000137">
    </div>
</form>
```

Result: open new tab, like https://www.sefaz.rs.gov.br/NFE/NFE-CCC.aspx?ErrKey=true&iCodUf=0&lCnpj=00110612000137

Second Way: Not Worked
**Read GET method in JS**

```
Input values:
<input type="text" name="lCnpj" id="lCnpj" value="00110612000137">
<input type="button" value="Get Input Values" id="retrieveInputValuesButton" />

<script>
    var cnpj = document.getElementById("lCnpj");
    var element = document.getElementById("retrieveInputValuesButton");
    element.onclick = function() {
      window.open("https://www.sefaz.rs.gov.br/NFE/NFE-CCC.aspx?ErrKey=true&iCodUf=0" + cnpj.value + "&exec=preencheParametros('CNPJ')");
    };
</script>
```

Result: open new tab, like https://www.sefaz.rs.gov.br/NFE/NFE-CCC.aspx?ErrKey=true&iCodUf=0&lCnpj=00110612000137&exec=preencheParametros('CNPJ')

Comment: Please add the relevant code *to the question*.  When your site code is updated, this question will become useless.  To preserve the long-term value of your question, the code causing the problem should always be available, even if your page is updated.

Comment: @Amy I reedited with the code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, but there is no way to pass in executable instructions to a website like that (unless they specifically provide you a way to do so). That would be a huge security risk if anyone could just inject code.

You could however try cooking something up with a Greasemonkey script. 
It's called Greasemonkey for Firefox, or Tapermonkey for Chrome